# onPreferenceChange not called on geometryReader frame change

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

`PreferenceKey` definition

```
struct ScrollPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0

  static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
    value = nextValue()
    
  }
}
```

Main Code

```
 ScrollView {
     GeometryReader { proxy in
                    
         Text("\(proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY)") // I can see changes
                        
         Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollPrefKey.self, value: proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).minY)
     } //MARK: END GeometryReader

     VStack {
       //main content
       Button(action: {}, label: {Text("myButton")})
     }

 }
 .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
 .onPreferenceChange(ScrollPrefKey.self, perform: { value in
    print(value)
    //DO SOME THINGS - but it never trigger
 })
```

1. This code works in Preview but not using simulator (iOS 16.1)
2. Replacing VStack with a static Color with defined height works
3. Embedding the entire content of scrollView including `GeometryReader` still doesn't work

Comment: I could not replicate your issue, all works well for me using Xcode 14.2, macos 13.2,
 targets ios 16.3 (tested on real devices and simulator iPhone 14), and macCatalyst.
 I have not tried ios 16.1, as I don't have it anymore, but I would be surprised if your
 issue is due to that.
 In my tests the `.onPreferenceChange(...)` is called with or without a `VStack{Text("testing")}`.

Comment: well, I didn't put a bounty without a good reason (: sadly, it's 100% the case for me.

Comment: ok, you are right @workingdogsupportUkraine partially  . It does work for me using your example but if you will change text to ` Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text("button text")
                        })` it will not work anymore. very very weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static func reduce(value: inout Self.Value, nextValue: () -> Self.Value)
```

`nextValue: () -> Self.Value` : This function allows for logic to reduce all those preferences to a single value, if multiple values are outputted by multiple different views, all using the same PreferenceKey.

When the view loads first time, the preference key will be updated from `defaultValue` to initial value. And since we have only one view producing the value with one preference key,  the `nextValue()` returns nil in this case.

`value: inout Self.Value`:
Though the `value`, which is keep accumulating through previous calls and keeps updating with the preference key value changes. So we should use the `value` here.

Update the `PreferenceKey` definition in the code with this:

```
struct ScrollPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}
```